# Access VBA: How to sum columns

Tags: ms-access

I need to do the sum of Costo1, Costo2 and Costo3 But I mean in a horizontal way. For example, with the ID field 119, I need the sum of $333.00 + $121.212.00 + $23.00 and so on:

[image: Table1]

Comment: Create a query. Calculate the total in the query. You don't store calculated data in tables.

Comment: Since the `Acta_ID` seems to be unique, there is no need to build a sum by `Acta_ID`, because that sum wouldn't differ from the details row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing this simple query it can be done:

SELECT [Costo1]+[Costo2]+[Costo3] AS Total FROM tblCostos;'

Comment: `NZ(Cost1,0)+...` if there's a chance of Null values in the field.